# Matlab R2016a glxna64 installation in ubuntu

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install the matlab on my ubuntu 14.04. I have downloaded the student trial version from mathworks. I downloaded a zip file. The other resources are telling me to unzip it and the open the installer. I did that but I cannot find the installer. [if i click on install it opens some text file which has some shell programming in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmBn2.png)

Please help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: I assume the file named `install` is the installer.

Comment: are you at all familiar with ubuntu? Try running install as a command like `./install.sh` or `./install`

Comment: @MZimmerman6 i tried the command ./install it gave me the following error.         shriniwas@shriniwas-300E4C-300E5C-300E7C:~/matlab$ ./install
./install: 1: eval: /home/shriniwas/matlab/bin/glnx86/install_unix: not found.      i am not familiar with the terminal and its commands. In the guide it says to run the installer as super user, how to do that ? i have extracted the files on a matlab folder in my home, so i changed my directory through terminal and then gave ./install command and i got the above error. please help.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 I found the command for super user which is sudo -i . but after that i tried sudo ./install an ./install it said no such file or directory, is there some specific place where i should extract the files ?

Comment: you must be in the same directory as your install file. `cd path/to/folder; sudo ./install`

Comment: @MZimmerman6 i went into the matlab folder by doing cd matlab and then i did sudo ./install but stil it says the doesnt exist. please help

Comment: I suggest you do some research on how to use Ubuntu/Linux because it is fairly difficult to help you don't understand the operating system. Also this is off-topic for stack overflow. Try searching on Youtube or your favorite video site for tutorials on how to install MATLAB on Ubuntu. There are plenty of videos.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 i am sorry if it was off topic. i tried to search on youtube but couldnt find tutorial for installing matlab in detail. anyways thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use **ISO images**:

**Assuming that image is named R2015b_glnxa64.iso, simply mount ISO:**

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/iso sudo mount -o ro,loop ./R2015b_glnxa64.iso
/media/iso
```

**run the installation script:**

```
sudo /media/iso/install
```

and if you want to install  (two DVDs/ISOs), you should use the same path for mounting both ISO images:

1.
mount DVD1 `sudo mount -o ro,loop /media/data/R2017a_glnxa64_dvd1.iso /media/iso`,
2.
install `sudo /media/iso/install` and wait for a pop-up window to change the disk,
3.
mount DVD2 `sudo mount -o ro,loop /media/data/R2017a_glnxa64_dvd2.iso /media/iso`

**and finally unmount image:**

Answer (score -2):

You can just install matlab with this one line command.

```
 sudo apt-get install matlab-gdf dynare-matlab libpdl-io-matlab-perl matlab-support matlab-support-dev matlab2tikz
```